# Which Relationship between Django Models

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, many-to-many, one-to-many

I'm trying to code a DB based web app with Python/Django and I have some issues figuring out which is the best approach for my purpose, so I'll try to explain myself the best way possible.

The DB stores objects that represent a videogame PG's Armor Pieces. Every piece has some positive/negative abilities scores: wearing a complete Armor set (Helmet, Jacket etc..), the scores for each ability sum up and can give different effects.
So, every armor piece can have different abilities, and each Ability can be shared between several Armor Pieces, but the scores for each Ability may be different for different Armor Pieces.

Once finished, this app should be able to find - if possible - a complete ArmorSet composed of 5 ArmorPiece which have the PieceAbility.scores necessary to activate one or more Effects the user would like.

```
from django.db import models


class Ability(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

class ArmorSetPart(models.Model):
    part = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.part

class WeaponClass(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.type

class Rank(models.Model):
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.rank
    
class PieceAbility(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Ability, related_name='pieces', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0, )

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name.name + ' ' + '{0:+}'.format(self.score)
    
class Material(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

class CraftMaterial(models.Model):
    material = models.ForeignKey(Material, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.material} x {self.quantity}'

class ArmorPiece(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    weapon_class = models.ForeignKey(WeaponClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    set_part = models.ForeignKey(ArmorSetPart, related_name='set_parts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rank = models.ForeignKey(Rank, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    slots = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    rarity = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    def_min = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    def_max = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    price = models.BigIntegerField()
    fire = models.IntegerField()
    water = models.IntegerField()
    ice = models.IntegerField()
    thund = models.IntegerField()
    drag = models.IntegerField()
    ability = models.ManyToManyField(PieceAbility, related_name='pieces')
    craft_mater = models.ManyToManyField(CraftMaterial, related_name='required_for')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name


class Effect(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    ability = models.ForeignKey(Ability, related_name='effects', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    necess_score = models.IntegerField(default=10, null=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

Now, in the code I wrote above you can see I choosed a ManytoMany relationship between ArmorPiece and PieceAbility, but I'm not satisfied due to the fact in this way DB stores every different PieceAbility.score for each ArmorPiece: if ArmorPiece1 has PieceAbilityA +1, and ArmorPiece2 has the same PieceAbility but with a different score like +4, I now have 2 instances of PieceAbility.
It doesn't seem very efficient to me and I wonder if there is a different/better way to do it.
The same issue shows up with the relationship between models CraftMaterial and ArmorPiece.

The first time I wrote ArmorPiece class there were several ability fields with their score field, like:

```
class ArmorPiece(models.Model):
    ability_one = models.ForeignKey(Ability, ...)
    score_one = models.IntegerField()
    ability_two = models.ForeignKey(Ability, ...)
    score_two = models.IntegerField()
```

I think this way is even worst.

I'm a novice. Surely I don't have enough experience to understand which approach is better, so I'm in your hands!

The videogame is an old gen Monster Hunter title, if it can help you understand what i mean, and please forgive my English, Thank you in advance!!